# Is the compiler required to diagnose violations of language syntax in templates?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

There is [an example in [temp.res.general]](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#example-7) which confuses me:

> ```cpp
> template<class T> class X {
>   // ...
>   void g(T t) {
>     +;              // may be diagnosed even if X​::​g is not instantiated
>   }
> };
> ```

The word "may" suggests that the compiler is allowed to diagnose `+;`, however, it isn't required to do so.  To my knowledge, `+;` is not valid C++ syntax.

If it is required to, where is the wording which proves it? If it isn't, how far are you able to take it?

```cpp
void g(T t) {
    +(()=/)(/)§(/)(/)/=)$§/%)=§(/&%=)§/(%)=§/%§;  // diagnostic required?
    }}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}};                         // diagnostic required?
}
```

It seems like the compiler has to match braces to know whether a syntax error takes place inside a template, or outside. This opens up two more questions:

1. Are syntax misues merely IFNDR in general, not just in templates?
2. Is the there any wording which says that brace matching has to take place?

##### Clarification

By "violation of language syntax" combining tokens in such a way that the grammatical rules of the language are violated because the token sequence cannot form a C++ translation unit.

`+;` does not match any rule in the C++ grammar, and presumably that needs to be diagnosed even if it is located within a template directly or indirectly ... does it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, compilers are required to diagnose violations of language syntax everywhere, and the example in the standard is misleading.

- `+;` is not a valid *[statement](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#nt:statement)*; therefore
- `{ +; }` is not a valid *[compound-statement](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block#nt:compound-statement)* and not a valid *[function-body](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#nt:function-body)*; therefore
- `void g() { +; }` is not a valid *[function-definition](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#nt:function-definition)* and not a valid *[member-declaration](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem.general#nt:member-declaration)*; therefore
- the definition of `X` is not a valid *[template-declaration](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.pre#nt:template-declaration)* and not an element of the *[declaration-seq](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:declaration-seq)* of the TU; therefore
- the entire *[translation-unit](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#nt:translation-unit)* is invalid

As you can see, a violation of language syntax inevitably "bubbles upwards" in the grammar, and also means that any containing template isn't a template in the first place.
If there is no containing template, and there isn't even a valid *[translation-unit](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#nt:translation-unit)*, then diagnostics are required because syntax violations fall under the umbrella of [diagnosable rules](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance.general#def:diagnosable_rules).

Unless "no diagnostic required" was explicitly stated, the following applies:

> [...] if a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule or an occurrence of a construct described in this document as “conditionally-supported” when the implementation does not support that construct, **a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message**.

- [[intro.compliance.general] p2.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance.general#2.3)

In conclusion, the `+;` example is misleading.
A possible way to improve it would be to use *"must be diagnosed"* instead of *"may be diagnosed"*.

---

*Note: I've submitted an [editorial pull request](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/6577) which fixes this wording.*